# Show a image from external URL inside chrome://newtab

Tags: chromium

Is it possible to use a `<img src="https://someurl">` in chome://newtab?

I've tried, but the following error is shown:

> FATAL:web_request_permissions.cc(311)] Check failed: extensions::ExtensionsBrowserClient::Get() ->IsWebUIAllowedToMakeNetworkRequests(*request.initiator). Unsupported network request from chrome://newtab/ for https://someurl

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you creating a new tab extension?

Comment: Yes, it has been created already.
Meanwhile i found a solution to display a image there.... in means I show it as a base64 string directly in the image tag.